# How can I display the resulting path when using mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, localhost

I am having a heck of a time trying to get an apache mod_rewrite rule to work.  The thing that is making the process the most difficult is that I have no way of knowing what the final output string is.  I continue to get 404 pages, but that doesn't tell me much except that I did something wrong.  Is there some method of echoing out the final rewrite rather than redirecting me to a 404?

. . . And just in case someone feels like helping me out with my original problem, I'm trying to make it so that anyone who goes to `/server/root/to/folder/public_html/` gets redirected to `/server/root/to/folder/public_html/destinationFolder/`.  Below is one of the hundreds of variations that I've tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond $1 !^(favicon\.ico|assets)

    RewriteRule ^public_html/(.*) destinationFolder/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: You're specifying a rewritebase which is the equivalent to a base tag within a HTML page, except it's for mod_rewrite.

Take a look at: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase

And let me know if you have further issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using system paths. Apache mod_rewrite only works with URLs (PT flag is implied in .htaccess files), that's your first error.

`public_html` is normally the root directory. For example: `http://mydomain.com`

Then, a complete rule set could be something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^(favicon\.ico|assets)  [NC]
RewriteRule  ^(.*)/?$    DestinationFolder/$1        [L]
```

Maps silently

`http://mydomain.com/Anything`

To:

`http://mydomain.com/DestinationFolder/Anything`

Except when `anything` is file `favicon.ico` or folder `/assets`

For permanent redirection, replace `[L]` with `[R=301,L]`

This is just an example. The rules and parameters have to be modified to meet the real requirements.

Comment: This is perfect.  It works like a charm with only a couple of tweeks.  Thank you!